# Cli-fi with vignette of men prying up concrete parking lot to reverse damage to the soil

Tags: story-identification, novel

It's a piece of cli-fi, climate fiction, set after nearly everyone has died. The Earth's climate has stabilized again but it's not hospitable. The very few survivors have satellite views and old recordings. What I remember is a brief vignette that describes how people realized too late that the environmental changes were an emergency. A film shows men prying up concrete slabs from a parking lot with hand tools to expose the soil again and "let the earth breathe." But images of the area they lived in now show nothing but scattered shrubs. No doubt, I could remember more if I could associate this bit with other memories, but I haven't succeeded after thinking about it for several months. What I do recall is that this is from a book written relatively recently (probably late 90s to 2010s), in English.

Comment: I've ransacked my book collection but I'm fairly sure this book isn't in it, so that means I'm reduced to Googling. But without any more specific information that's going to be a challenge :-(

Comment: Thank you for going to that effort. It's not in my current library either, though it's likely a book I once owned..